# Can not restore postgreSQL dump file in AWS

Tags: django, database, postgresql, restore

I tried to restore PostgreSQL database from dump file in AWS but an error occurred.

it said

```
pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade the PostgreSQL version and then try again.